# Help creating a formula for a probability problem

Tags: distributions

I was thinking of a probability problem, but I'm having trouble thinking about what the formula would be to solve it.

Say you need 10 events to win a game. 10% of the time you press a button, it triggers the event. 5% of the time you pull a lever, it triggers the event. You push the button continuously until you win. Then you pull the lever continuously until you win.

What is the probability that you needed to pull the lever at least 75 more times than the number of times you pushed the button? How about X more times?

Note: This is purely for personal interest and I created the problem myself. I have an idea that the answer is perhaps logarithmic in growth.

Comment: Now that I think a little more, it probably looks like a normal distribution centered on 100

Comment: The distribution of lever pulls $L$ until the event is geometric with $p_L = 0.1$ and the distribution of button pushes $B$ until the event is geometric with $p_B = 0.05.$ You want $P(B - L \ge 75).$ You need to be a little careful with the details because there are two different ways to formulate a geometric dist'n in common usage. Roughly speaking, one of them has $E(B) = 1/p_B$ and $E(L) = 1/p_L.$ The average difference might be something like $20 - 10 = 10.$ // I don't suppose it's useful to try to approximate a geometric distribution by a normal distribution.

Answer (score 0):

**Comment** continued: In R statistical software a geometric random variable counts the number
of failures before the first success. Here is one way to do a brief
simulation of your problem in R. Notice that I have added $1$ to the
values generated by R in order to count the number of trials *until* the
event occurs, instead of the number of trials *before.*

Maybe this simulation will help you to decide exactly how 
you want to frame your Question for an analytic solution. It seems that
a difference $B-L$ of 7 or more is much more likely (about $0.48)$ than a difference of 75 or more (about $0.01$ or $0.02).$

```
set.seed(2019);  m=10^6
L = rgeom(m, .1) + 1;  B = rgeom(m, .05) + 1
mean(B);  mean(L)
[1] 20.01641   # aprx E(B) = 20
[1] 9.980865   # aprx E(L) = 10
mean(B - L);  mean(B-L >= 7);  mean(B-L >= 75)
[1] 10.03555   # aprx E(B-L) = 10
[1] 0.482099   # aprx P(B-L >= 7)
[1] 0.014811   # aprx P(B-L >= 75)
hist(B - L, prob=T, br=50, col="skyblue2")
abline(v=75, col="red")
```

[image]

**Addendum for 10 events** using negative binomial distributions:

```
set.seed(2019);  m=10^6
L = rnbinom(m, 10, .1) + 10;  B = rnbinom(m, 10, .05) + 10
mean(B);  mean(L)
[1] 200.0137
[1] 100.0299
mean(B - L);  mean(B-L >= 7);  mean(B-L >= 75)
[1] 99.98382
[1] 0.927744
[1] 0.625805
hist(B - L, prob=T, br=50, col="skyblue2")
abline(v = 75, col="red")
```

[image]

I will leave it to you to try a normal approximation.

*Note:* A simulation program will give slightly different answers on each run. With a million trials each for buttons and levers, probabilities
should be accurate to about two decimal places. To repeat the exact
simulation shown, retain the `set.seed` statement; to do a fresh
simulation, omit that statement or choose a different seed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I think this answer is missing something though, there needs to be 10 events to win the game,  not just once! I imagined the expected average would be 100 more times since you'd expect 100 button presses to win the game and 200 lever presses to win the game.

Comment: That could be simulated too. That would use a negative binomial distribution. In that case the distribution of the difference isn't exactly normal, but a normal approximation might give you a decent approximation.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will look into negative binomial distributions.